# How to extract (recognize) book title from the article?

Tags: python, nltk

Is there any good method to extract (recognize) book title from the article using nltk or something else?

I can recognize author names using nltk, so my idea is to get list of book titles with authors from some external source and when I recognize author name then I could take a list of this author's books from external source and look for them in the text.

but I'm not convinced about this solution because I need external source with all books and I don't have such a source and this solution seems a bit like "brute force" for me.

can you direct me on topics that will help me with this problem?

Comment: Why is this tagged “machine-learning”? If you really want an ML solution, just train the network on a bunch of examples with that list of book titles, and it should (a) come up with a heuristic that covers most cases (e.g., a string in Book Title Case is a book, or maybe only _Title Case in Italics_, or however they appear in your source text), and (b) learn the most common exceptions. Then you don’t need to keep checking that list. But it’s may be a lot less reliable than a rule-based system rather than more. And it will definitely be less reliable than explicit checking.

Comment: Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: Meanwhile, if you want something cleverer than “brute force” always searching every string: if you can isolate the rule used in your source text (like italics with two or more capitals in one sentence), you can use that. If, say, it has an acceptable number of false negatives but too many false positives, you can do a hybrid that applies the rule, then filters the positives by searching the source. Or maybe a fuzzy rule that quantifies how likely it is to be a book title based on format, then filter the borderline ones. And so on.

Answer (score 4):

Given sufficient training data, there is a wonderful python library for achieving things like this called https://github.com/snipsco/snips-nlu

What you might want to do is grab examples from as many articles that include book titles as you can, follow the documentation on that repository, and you should be able to glean book titles from articles assuming they follow a similar pattern as your example data.

I'm not 100% positive that this is a task for machine learning however. There may be an easier way, such as looking for words/phrases that are in quotes, are italicized, etc. Humans don't necessarily know that a bunch of words are the title of a book, so we invented punctuation to explicitly make that clear. It seems to me there should be some use for that syntax in your solution if possible.

Comment: This could be a good use for ML if there are lots of ambiguous cases. For example, in plaintext without italics, single-word titles are tricky, and weird titles like Bible books are always tricky, but a human could probably still identify 4 Ezra as a book title in this sentence even if every Bible they’ve seen has no such book and counts it as part of a book named 2 Esdras, and so could a suitably trained ML. Without any idea of what the OP’s corpus is, it’s hard to guess whether that’s appropriate, but I think this is a useful answer for others even if it isn’t for this OP.

Comment: Yes, I agree. As with any task regarding data, OP should probably research their source and ask themselves how *they, a human* would solve the problem. This will get them closer to teaching a computing to do the same thing. Machine learning sounds overkill at first thought.